# Liquibase Maven Plugin: how to increase changelog lock wait time?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I have a maven spring project using liquibase. At the moment we have multiple instances deploying but sometimes the deployment will fail because the lock will last more than five minutes, due to the size of the changes.

How can I change the changlog wait lock time? I'm using the liquibase maven plugin, for which I didn't find obvious ways to configure this parameter, but I know that a command parameter exists: https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/command-parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [changelog-lock-wait-time-in-minutes](https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/changelog-lock-wait-time-in-minutes.html) says that you can also set this parameter via `liquibase.properties` file:

```
liquibase.changelogLockWaitTimeInMinutes: <int>
```

Or via Java system property:

```
Mac/Linux syntax:
JAVA_OPTS=-Dliquibase.changelogLockWaitTimeInMinutes=<int>

Windows syntax:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dliquibase.changelogLockWaitTimeInMinutes=<int>
```

For `liquibase.properties` configuration example with liquibase-maven-plugin check out this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app#1-plugin-configuration)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency> 
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <configuration>                  
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration>                
    </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

Comment: Where should I put this liquibase.properties file htshame? In the resources/ folder of my spring application? Will it be automatically detected?

Comment: I've updated my answer with `liquibase.properties` configuration example